# check whether a directory contains all (and only) the listed files

Tags: bash, shell, unit-testing, filesystems, sh

I'm writing unit-tests to test file-IO functions.
There's no formalized test-framework in my target language, so my idea is to run a little test program that somehow manipulates files in a test-directory, and after that checks the results in a little shell script.

To evaluate the output, I want to check a given directory whether all expected files are there and no other files have been created during the test.

My first attempt goes like this:

```sh
set -e

test -e "${test_dir}/a.txt"
test -e "${test_dir}/b.txt"
test -d "${test_dir}/dir"
find "${test_dir}" -mindepth 1 \
     -not -wholename "${test_dir}/a.txt" \
     -not -wholename "${test_dir}/b.txt" \
     -not -wholename "${test_dir}/dir" \
    | grep . && exit 1 || true
```

This properly detects whether there are two files `a.txt` and `b.txt`, and a subdirectory `dir/` in the `${test_dir}`.
If there happens to be a file `c.txt`, the test should and will fail.

However, this doesn't scale well.
There are dozens of unit-tests and each has a different set of files/directories, so I find myself repeating lines very similar to the above again and again.

So I'd rather wrap the above into a function call like so:

```sh
if checkdirectory "${test_dir}" a.txt b.txt dir/ dir/subdir/ dir/.hidden.txt; then
  echo "ok"
else
  echo "ko"
fi
```

Unfortunately I have no clue how to implement `checkdirectory` (esp. the `find` invocation with multiple `-not -wholename ...` stanzas gives me headache).

To add a bit of fun, the constraints are:

- support both (and differentiate between) files and directories
- *must* (EDITed from *should*) run on Linux, macOS & MSYS2/MinGW, therefore:
- *POSIX* if possible (in reality it will be `bash`, but probably bash<<4! so no fancy features)

#### EDIT

some more constraints (these didn't make it into original my late-night question; so just consider them "extra constraints for bonus points")

- the test-directory may contain subdirectories and files in  subdirectories (up to an arbitrary depth), so any check needs to operate on more than just the top-level directory
- ideally, the paths may contain weirdo characters like spaces, linebreaks,... (this is really unit-testing. we do want to test for such cases)
- the `testdir` is more often than not some randomly generated directory using `mktemp -d`, so it would be nice if we could avoid hardcoding it in the tests
- no assumptions about the underlying filesystem can be made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we have a directory tree as an example:

```
$test_dir/a.txt
$test_dir/b.txt
$test_dir/dir/c.txt
$test_dir/dir/"d e".txt
$test_dir/dir/subdir/
```

then would you please try:

```
#!/bin/sh

checkdirectory() {
    local i
    local count
    local testdir=$1
    shift
    for i in "$@"; do
        case "$i" in
            */) [ -d "$testdir/$i" ] || return 1 ;;     # check if the directory exists
            *)  [ -f "$testdir/$i" ] || return 1 ;;     # check if the file exists
        esac
    done
    # convert each filename to just a newline, then count the lines
    count=`find "$testdir" -mindepth 1 -printf "\n" | wc -l`
    [ "$count" -eq "$#" ] || return 1
    return 0
}

if checkdirectory "$test_dir" a.txt b.txt dir/ dir/c.txt "dir/d e.txt" dir/subdir/; then
    echo "ok"
else
    echo "ko"
fi
```

Comment: jeez. that looks like a good idea. I do want to check recursively (as the tests involve subdirectories and directories) in order to also allow for whitespace in filenames, i'll guess instead of using `ls -l` i'm heading for `find -exec echo found ;`

Comment: actually, the proper command for counting the number of elements in the directory would be `find "${testdir}" -mindepth 1 -printf . | wc -c`

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. One question. How do we feed the filenames in the subdirectories? May I assume the pathnames are provided as described in the answer by Léa Gris?

Comment: i've updated the question to use content in subdirs when invoking my wishlist function.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've updated my answer according to your requirements. Now it should work if the pathnames contain special characters such as whitespace or newline. It still complies old `sh` (hopefully).

Comment: as @LéaGris pointed out, `find -printf` requires GNU find, which is typically not available on macOS. a solution that seems to work is to use `find "${testdir}" -mindepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0  -I'{}' echo | wc -l`. (sidenote: is there anything specific as to why you prefer `\`\`` over `$()`?)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback as well as the improvement plan. The usage of the `find` with the `-print0` option sounds to be the best solution. BTW the reason that I have used the backquote syntax is just because I thought you may prefer backward compatibility. I remember now the `$(..)` syntax is supported by POSIX as well.

Answer (score 1):

One easy fast way would be to compare the output of `find` with a reference string:

Lets start with an expected directory and files structure:

```
d/FolderA/filexx.csv
d/FolderA/filexx.doc
d/FolderA/Sub1
d/FolderA/Sub2
```

`testassert`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

assertDirContent() {
  read -r -d '' s < <(find "$1" -printf '%y %p\n')
  [ "$2" = "$s" ]
}

testref='d d/FolderA/
f d/FolderA/filexx.csv
f d/FolderA/filexx.doc
d d/FolderA/Sub1
d d/FolderA/Sub2'

if assertDirContent 'd/FolderA/' "$testref"; then
  echo 'ok'
else
  echo 'Directory content assertion failed'
fi
```

Testing it:

```sh
$ ./testassert
ok
$ touch d/FolderA/unwantedfile
$ ./testassert
Directory content assertion failed
$ rm d/FolderA/unwantedfile
$ ./testassert
ok
$ rmdir d/FolderA/Sub1
$ ./testassert
Directory content assertion failed
$ mkdir d/FolderA/Sub1
$ ./testassert
ok
$ rmdir d/FolderA/Sub2
# Replace with a file instead of a directory
touch d/FolderA/Sub2
$ ./testassert
Directory content assertion failed
```

Now if you add timestamps and other info like permissions, owner, group to the `find -printf` output, you can also check all these matches the asserted string output.

Comment: i guess that won't work if the paths contain weird stuff like linebreaks (currently they don't; but given that this is for unit-testing, it probably *is* i good idea to have such use-cases...). otoh, I very much do like the idea of  being able to check for other meta-data!

Comment: anyhow, the real problem with this solution seems to be that it relies on `find` returning the data in a given order (the same as the declared in `${testref}`), which I think is a wrong assumption.

Comment: @umläute I'd like to see case where the output of `find -printf` is not predictable. About files with space or newlines or tabs or non-printable characters: These are not an issue as long as they are compared with the expected output of it. If you don't have access to the GNU Tools `find -printf`, you can fall-back to `glob` and `globstar` filename expansion `printf -v s '%s\n' "$1/"**`. It won't check the type but it is warranted to always return entries in the exact same order.

Comment: good point about `find -printf` requiring GNU-tools (just now I returned to this question as i'm bitten by it on macOS).

Comment: regarding the sorting of `find`: as mentioned in the requirements, this is supposed to run on multiple platforms (Linux, macOS, MSYS/MinGW), so no assumption can be made about the underlying filesystem (sorry that I didn't make this explicit in my Q; fixed now). my understanding is, that `find` will sort as the fileystem-implementation sees fit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by differentiating between files and directories since your last `if` statement is somehow binary. Here's what worked for me:

```
#! /bin/bash

function checkdirectory()
{
        test_dir="${1}"
        shift
        content="$@"

        for file in ${content}
        do
                [[ -z "${test_dir}/${file}" ]] && return 1
        done

        # -I is meant to be appended to "ls" to ignore the files in order to check if other files exist.  
        matched=" -I ${content// / -I } -I ${test_dir}"

        [[ -e `ls $matched` ]] && return 1

        return 0
}


if checkdirectory /some/directory a.txt b.txt dir; then
        echo "ok"
else
        echo "ko"
fi
```

Comment: with "differentiating between files and directories", i mean that i want to check for both the existence and the type of a given path (that is: a check for a *directory* `dir` should not return true if there is a *file* of the same name)

Comment: i'm always afraid of using the [output of `ls`]. also is the last `-I` (before the `${test_dir}`) an oversight and should be removed?

Comment: and i'm not sure about what you meant with "somewhat binary if". i'd very much prefer a POSIX solution, but could resort to bash<<4 as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution i dreamed up during the night.

It destroys the test-data, so might not be usable in many cases (though it might just work for paths generated on-the-fly during unit tests):

```sh
checkdirectory() {
    local i
    local testdir=$1
    shift
    # try to remove all the listed files
    for i in "$@"; do
        if [ "x${i}" = "x${i%/}" ]; then
            rm "${testdir}/${i}" || return 1
        fi
    done

    # the directories should now be empty,
    # so try to remove those dirs that are listed
    for i in "$@"; do
        if [ "x${i}" != "x${i%/}" ]; then
            rmdir "${testdir}/${i}" || return 1
        fi
    done

    # finally ensure that no files are left
    if find "${testdir}" -mindepth 1 | grep . >/dev/null ; then
        return 1
    fi
    return 0
}
```

When invoking the `checkdirectory` function, deeper directories must come first (that is `checkdirectory foo/bar/ foo/` rather than <del>`checkdirectory foo/ foo/bar/`</del>).